# Renaming Cyrillic file names

Tags: python, file-rename, cyrillic

What I have in mind is iterating through a folder to check whether the file names contain any Cyrillic characters, if they do, rename those files to something else.

How could I do this ?

Comment: Which version of python? 2.x and 3k are very different w/r/t string handling.

Comment: You might find [`Unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) useful.

Comment: [transliterate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate) might be useful too.

Comment: You can have it shorter and probably faster using `ord()` as suggested by @markransom. See the [updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27697038/1797098).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Python 3**
This one checks each character of the passed string, whether it's in the Cyrillic block and returns `True` if the string has a Cyrillic character in it. Strings in Python3 are unicode by default. The function encodes each character to *utf-8* and checks whether this yields two bytes matching the table block that contains Cyrillic characters.

```
def isCyrillic(filename):
    for char in filename:            
        char_utf8 = char.encode('utf-8')      # encode to utf-8 

        if len(char_utf8) == 2 \              # check if we have 2 bytes and if the
            and 0xd0 <= char_utf8[0] <= 0xd3\ # first and second byte point to
            and 0x80 <= char_utf8[1] <= 0xbf: # Cyrillic block (unicode U+0400-U+04FF)
            return True

    return False
```

**Same function using [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#ord) as suggested in comment**

```
def isCyrillicOrd(filename):
    for char in filename:                  
        if 0x0400 <= ord(char) <= 0x04FF:    # directly checking unicode code point
            return True

    return False
```

**Test Directory**

```
cycont
   |---- asciifile.txt
   |---- кириллфайл.txt
   |---- украї́нська.txt
   |---- संस्कृत.txt
```

**Test**

```
import os
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('G:/cycont'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename, isCyrillic(filename), isCyrillicOrd(filename))
```

**Output**

```
asciifile.txt False False
кириллфайл.txt True True
украї́нська.txt True True
संस्कृत.txt False False
```

Comment: Why go to the trouble of converting to UTF-8 when you can test the `ord()` of the character directly?

Comment: @markransom Easy to answer: I wasn't aware of `ord()`. Made an appropriate update.

Answer (score 3):

**Python 2:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def check_value(value):
    try:
        value.decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

**Python 3:**

Python 3 'str' object doesn't have the attribute 'decode'. So you can use the encode as follows.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def check_value(value):
    try:
        value.encode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Then you can gather your file names, and pass them through the check_value function.

Comment: I had a hard time identifying the difference, here, between Python 2 and Python 3 -- made change to help out.

Comment: I updated it to 'why' there is a difference. Thanks.

Comment: Won't this return False for those non-Cyrillic characters that are also non-ascii (e.g. Greek)?

Comment: @JustinR. Yes, with embert has answered using the unicode block. At least mine will detect non-standard ascii characters. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library that was written for this: Python's [transliterate lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate/1.5).

So, first you need to get your file names. For that, use os.listdir():

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
files = [ f for f in listdir(dir) if isfile(join(dir,f)) ]
```

Now, you can look at each file in files, substitute any characters as needed:

```
import transliterate
newName = translit(filename, 'ru', reversed=True)
```

Then just rename the files with [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html):

```
os.rename(filename, newName)
```

Comment: The problem with listdir() is that instead of returning file names in cyrillic, it gives you back question marks.

Comment: @MarioGeuenich: The question marks are due to a mismatch between the encoding of the bytes in the filename and the encoding of your terminal. It is note `listdir`'s fault. Also not that if you pass `listdir` a unicode, then it will return unicode filenames. However, the burden is still on you to encode the unicode with the  encoding that your terminal expects, and to make sure that the unicode *can* be encoded with that codec. This can be a [problem on Windows](http://bugs.python.org/issue1602).